# Number pad not working with vi and Putty?

Tags: terminal, putty

When I am editing a file in `vim` via SSH, I will try to use the number pad on my keyboard to enter long numbers (like IP addresses).  `Vim` does not seem to like that very much.  I am using PuTTY for Windows to SSH into a computer running Debian.

Pressing `123` enters me this regardless of if I am in insert mode or not:

```
s
r
q
```

When I use the "normal" (not number pad) number keys, everything works fine.  What is going on here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your terminal (PuTTY) is configured to send escape sequences for keypad keys, rather than digits. This is called “application keypad mode” in Unix terminal terminology.

You can [configure Vim to understand these escape sequences](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/PuTTY_numeric_keypad_mappings).

Alternatively, you can configure PuTTY to send digits. In the configuration, [in the Keyboard panel](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.64/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-appkeypad), turn off application keypad mode. Alternatively, turn it off altogether [in the Features panel](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.64/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-features-application).